# Virdi Unis error when distribute users data

Tags: c#, fingerprint

I m using Unis 3.1.1 with Virdi Ac7000 and gathered all employees fingerprints on one device and when trying to distribute users data all over other devices all emp data is transfered very well except the fingerprint 
I tried on Access DB and Oracle and the same problem 
is there any conf. has to be done or this is a bug in UNIS

I downloaded the VIRDI SDK  from

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B06Dxl8hzdKDZllHYlloU3lZbUk&usp=sharing

and tried to run the server within visual studio but also gave me 1002 error and didn't start although the example UCSAPI_Demo.exe in runs very well

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

using UCSAPICOMLib;

using UCBioBSPCOMLib;

namespace UCSAPI_DemoCSharp

{

    public partial class test : Form
    {
    public UCSAPICOMLib.UCSAPI ucsAPI;
    public UCSAPI m_Api = new UCSAPI();


    public test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        m_Api.ServerStart(999, 9870);
        MessageBox.Show(m_Api.ErrorCode.ToString("X4"));


    }

    private void test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to the dlls, your application is not accessing it well.
Pls, try putting all the VIRDI dlls, in the same folder of your application.